# Variable substitution inside plpgsql functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

To be able to create different instances of an application inside one database, like for example test staging, I would like to use variables for the schema name. Everything works when creating tables or sequences, but I can not figure out an elegant way to use variables inside functions. I have read already some articles 
about dollar-quoted string constants, but I still hope to find a solution.

Currently running PostgreSQL 11.

Here is the code:

Works as expeced, setting schema_name to sc and using the variable during DDL:

```
\set schema_name sc

CREATE SEQUENCE :schema_name.S_VT_KEY INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE OWNED BY NONE;

create table :schema_name.vartest (
  VT_KEY   BIGINT,
  DESCRIPTION TEXT);
```

And now the function:

```
create or replace function :schema_name.fvartest(
  p_desc  TEXT)
  RETURNS bigint
  language 'plpgsql'
  COST 100.0
  VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $function$
DECLARE
  p_key bigint;
BEGIN

  select nextval('sc.S_VT_KEY') into p_key; -- (1)

  insert into sc.vartest (VT_KEY, DESCRIPTION) -- (2)
      values (p_key, p_desc);

  return p_key;

END $function$;
```

In case (1)
I would like to use something like:

```
  select nextval(:schema_name || '.S_VT_KEY') into p_key;
```

In case (2)

```
  insert into :schema_name.vartest (VT_KEY, DESCRIPTION) -- (2)
```

Any variant so far renders an error message:

Using directly:

```
select nextval(:schema_name || '.S_VT_KEY') into p_key;
```

renders a syntax error

```
psql:test/testcase001.sql:29: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 12:  select nextval(:schema_name || '.S_VT_KEY') into p_key; -- ...
```

Escaping, compiles but does not run:

```
select nextval($e$:schema_name$e$ || '.S_VT_KEY') into p_key; -- (1)

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select nextval($e$:schema_name$e$ || '.S_VT_KEY')"
```

Almost there, using same delimiters, substitues the variable but does render a syntax error:

```
select nextval($function$ :'schema_name' $function$ || '.S_VT_KEY') into p_key; -- (1)

LINE 12:  select nextval($function$ 'sc' $function$ || '.S_VT_KEY')
```

Maybe there is a way in PostgreSQL 12?

Comment: Can you pass schema name in as an argument, so you don't have to use the `:`-prefixed session var?

Comment: Hi @richyen, passing the schema name as an argument is possible, but solves only half of the problem. You can create a string with the sequence name passing it to the nextval() function. It will not help with the prefix for table names (2) like in select or update. Additionally you need to pass the variable to every function which is redundant and not very elegant.

Comment: I guess I would go for dynamic SQL. Have a look at the ```plpgsql``` command ```EXECUTE``` (which is not the same as the SQL command with the same name): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: In combination with an argument that gets the ```:schema_name``` as default. So you will not need to access the variable inside the dollar-quoting

Comment: "*create different instances of an application inside one database*" - I would recommend to create multiple databases (inside the same cluster) instead

Comment: Just `SET search_path= testschema, pg_catalog;` at the top of your script(s); maybe via an include file. (and, in this case **dont** schema-qualify your table names)

Comment: Dear @all, thanks for all of your hints and answers. Dynamic SQL would be also a way, but makes the code more unreadable. Creating always a new database with a default schema would be a way also, but on the other hand I always wondered in the last 30 yrs or so, why all the legacy code of databases is not using schemas, as this could separate applications easily. (This thinking arises from working in **really big** companies, where databases are set up by different departments and you have to wait some weeks to get one.)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution which works for now, but is by far not that elegant. I'm using bash variable substitution and it seems to work for the two cases mentioned above:

```
#!/bin/bash

export schema_name="sc"

psql postgresql://<user>:<pwd>@<host>/<db>  << EOF


create or replace function ${schema_name}.fvartest(
  p_desc  TEXT)
  RETURNS bigint
  language 'plpgsql'
  COST 100.0
  VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS \$function\$
DECLARE
    p_key bigint;
BEGIN

    select nextval('${schema_name}.S_VT_KEY') into p_key; -- (1)

    insert into ${schema_name}.vartest (VT_KEY, DESCRIPTION) -- (2)
        values (p_key, p_desc);

    return p_key;

END \$function\$;

    select ${schema_name}.fvartest('bla bla');
    select * from ${schema_name}.vartest;

EOF
```

But now I have to put the code into a bash script and escape the $function$ Postges style $$ notation. Maybe there is still a better way, would love to hear from you.